# Can't get img and links inside div?

Tags: html, css

This is my code and tried everything I could think of to place my image in the top middle and links on the top right corner.

Whatever I try doesn't align them in the same div and makes things wacky.
Here is my code:

```css
#header img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
}

.login a{
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <img src="img/raystratos.png"/>
    <div class="login">
            <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="#login">Log In</a>
            <a href="#shoppingcart">Shopping Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you like to happen when there's not enough room to show them side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute positioning:

```
#header { position: relative; }
.login { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to do this and also if you want to divide this row into 3 equal width columns you add another div inside the container and then add flex:1 property to each child element inside the #header.

```css
#header {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
#header img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    flex: 1;
}
.equalFlex {
  flex: 1;
}
.login a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1;
}
.login{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="equalFlex"></div>
    <img src="img/raystratos.png"/>
    <div class="login">
            <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="#login">Log In</a>
            <a href="#shoppingcart">Shopping Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the image is no longer centered.

Comment: I edited the post but the problem here is that you dont have enough width to center the image and have equal portion on left and right. your right side div for log-in has greater width than the container and thus can not be in lined. you can still refer www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html for more info on flex.